# How can I specify exact ciphers for my Apache TLS server

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have a web server. I configured the TLS versions I want to enable using:

```
sudo gedit mysitecom.conf
```

Inside the `.conf` I listed the desired versions using (as an example): `SSLProtocol -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2`

I want to make a test server with one or few specific ciphersuites. How to do this? Say I want one ciphersuite in a test, and two ciphersuites in the second test. What is the right way to specify exact ciphersuite e.g. `DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256` (not a family of ciphers)?

Comment: This is not really a security question but about the specific syntax in your servers configuration. How to do this is described in your web servers documentation and can easily be found when searching for [apache cipher](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+cipher).

Answer (score 2):

Using the [SSLCipherSuite directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite), you can enter a colon-separated cipher-spec string.  While this is commonly seen containing aliases like `MEDIUM` or `aNULL`, it can include any valid OpenSSL cipher, specified like `EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA`.

The full list of ciphers available is determined by which version of OpenSSL you're using.  You can use [`openssl ciphers`](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_ciphers.1.asp) to view the list as installed on your system.

And if you're already going down this route, you might want to leverage the expertise of Qualys' [SSL and TLS Deployment Best Practices](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices) which includes both recommended ciphers and other relevant portions of the configuration.